# Unable to get display names (sAMAccountName) of groups from Graph API call

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, .net-core-3.1

I have a working Azure app that gives me the group names when I call
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group

However, I have tried to recreate the app several times, and checked all settings in App Registrations and Enterprise Applications to match the original app - but can never get the group names in the new apps (created in the last 24 hours, if that is relevant).

API Permissions:

- Group.Read.All
- GroupMember.Read.All
- User.Read

App is created using these steps

- App registrations, add, Single tenant
- Quickstart, Mobile and desktop applications, Desktop, Make this change for me
- Token configuration, Add groups claim, Security groups, set all to sAMAccountName
- API Permissions, add Group.Read.All and GroupMember.Read.All
- Permission granted using “Grant admin consent for Default Directory”

There must be another setting somewhere else that I am missing, which I thought to post here to uncover, thinking it might help someone else with the same problem.

FYI fragment of group result that I get:

```
     "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v2/5ed71832-327b-4b98-b68a-6c54ff1717c0/directoryObjects/2f95e1d3-c7cf-4796-92a2-df844feb52d0/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group",
     "id": "12345678-c7cf-4796-92a2-df844feb5eee",
     "deletedDateTime": null,
     "classification": null,
     "createdDateTime": null,
     "creationOptions": [],
     "description": null,
     "displayName": null,       <<<<<<<<<< why is this null???
```

Answer (score 0):

When an application queries a relationship that returns a directoryObject type collection, if it does not have permission to read a certain derived type, members of that type are returned but with limited information. This could potentially be a reason for you seeing a 'null' value.

Also for using the **transitive memberOf** endpoint, I suggest you use directory level permissions.
[image]

Refer Documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-transitivememberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I have already added Read as well as ReadWrite permissions for Directory, Group and GroupMember to cover all bases. From the App Registration side, defined them and clicked Grant Consent. On Enterprise Apps\Permissions end, clicked again and Granted. I have however found that it works AFTER I specifically crafted a grant URI including these specific scopes, visiting as an admin and granting manually. Question is, is there a bug with Grant Consent in Enterprise Apps\Permissions?

Comment: The developers of multi-tenant application should also understand how to generate admin consent url for requesting admin consent for their applications. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint
Also, if an Azure AD global administrator has configured the User can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf option to false, then only Global Administrator can consent this application.This option is tenant wide and cannot be controlled on per-app basis.